# Usage of this keyword inside parameter c#

Tags: c#, this

I have a class:

```
public static class PictureBoxExtensions
{
    public static Point ToCartesian(this PictureBox box, Point p)
    {
        return new Point(p.X, p.Y - box.Height);
    }

    public static Point FromCartesian(this PictureBox box, Point p)
    {
        return new Point(p.X, box.Height - p.Y);
    }
}
```

My question is what is the use of the `this` keyword in front of `PictureBox`, as opposed to leaving out the keyword?

Comment: See the Edit. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The extension method is called like an instance method, but is actually a static method. The instance pointer "this" is a parameter.

And:
You must specify the this-keyword before the appropriate parameter you want the method to be called upon.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string UppercaseFirstLetter(this string value)
    {
        // Uppercase the first letter in the string this extension is called on.
        if (value.Length > 0)
        {
            char[] array = value.ToCharArray();
            array[0] = char.ToUpper(array[0]);
            return new string(array);
        }
        return value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Use the string extension method on this value.
        string value = "dot net perls";
        value = value.UppercaseFirstLetter(); // Called like an instance method.
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

see http://www.dotnetperls.com/extension for more info.

**Edit: try below example once and again with commenting

```
pb.Location=pb.FromCartesian(new Point(20, 20));
```

to see the result**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
            pb.Size = new Size(200, 200);
            pb.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            pb.Location=pb.FromCartesian(new Point(20, 20));
            Controls.Add(pb);
        }
    }

    public static class PictureBoxExtensions
    {
        public static Point ToCartesian(this PictureBox box, Point p)
        {
            return new Point(p.X, p.Y - box.Height);
        }

        public static Point FromCartesian(this PictureBox box, Point p)
        {
            return new Point(p.X, box.Height - p.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This class contains extension methods.

The `this` keyword means that the method is an extension. So the method `ToCartesian` in your example extends the `PictureBox` class, so that you can write:

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
Point p = pb.ToCartesian(oldPoint);
```

For more about extension methods, see the documentation on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: This is a correct answer, no need to downvote it!

Comment: There is. Your initial answer was "This class contains extension methods.". There was no need for that. You could have easily be a bit more explaining.

Comment: Patience, you must have. -- Yoda